# How to convert ECMAScript 12 to ECMAScript 10

Tags: javascript, ecma, ecmascript-2021, ecmascript-2019

I wrote a JS File, some of the codes in it are in ECMAScript 12. The problem is all my devices support only ECMAScript 10.
This was the file [Javascript](https://rko-monopoly.web.app/assets/js/scriptES12.js)
Is there any online converters available, or how can I do it manually?

Comment: There is not a huge difference in the ECMA-2021 vs the ECMA-2019 version. Have you tested just running your code on your devices? Usually it's just very few things the console might complain about that can easily be fixed manually (depending on the size of your code base)

Comment: babel + core-js, but your request sounds a bit weird, what devices are these, and what features of ES2021 do you really use? Also, requests for a tool/library are theoretically OT here.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I have an iPhone 6 with Safari 12.1. It doesn't support ESMA 12 but, It does support ESMA 10.  I don't know what features of ESMA 12 I use. The script was perfectly working on chrome on my laptop and suddenly in safari, it doesn't work. I didn't know that this question was off-topic, sorry. Where should I ask this type of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Babel will basically let you write modern JS code and then it can transpile it to "more primitive" code in order to run on a larger set of devices.

There are a bunch of options and a bunch of ways you can go about using it, but using the [env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) preset and specifying your `targets` is probably a good place to start.